# Any way of prioritizing order Mongod loads things into memory after startup?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

My use case will perhaps seem strange on first inspection however I believe in principle what I'm doing is a good way of scaling up massively in a short space of time without any impact on live service.

Our live database is run on a 3 member multi-region replica set on Amazon EC2. We backup regularly by snapshotting the EBS journal and data volumes. It is therefore super easy to spin up standalone clones of our database based on the most recent snapshot. We periodically have some heavy/complex aggregation jobs that require us to do stuff programmatically not possible in aggregation pipeline and need to pull large amounts of data from the database. Have found that pulling the data from active replica set members hampers performance and have therefore been spinning up boxes with standalone mongo servers that contain data from the latest snapshot. This works really nicely though it seems to take around 30 mins before the mongo servers become performant which I guess is due to all indices etc being loaded into memory.

The thing is that I only actually want to access one or two collections from the database. I'm wondering if there is a way to prioritize the collections I wish to use or else drop the collections I don't want without loading them into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of what you are experiencing is a performance hit for new EBS volumes that have been created from a snapshot. From the EC2 documentation:

> When you create a new EBS volume or restore a volume from a snapshot,
>   the back-end storage blocks are allocated to you immediately. However,
>   the first time you access a block of storage, it must be either wiped
>   clean (for new volumes) or instantiated from its snapshot (for
>   restored volumes) before you can access the block. This preliminary
>   action takes time and can cause a 5 to 50 percent loss of IOPS for
>   your volume the first time each block is accessed. For most
>   applications, amortizing this cost over the lifetime of the volume is
>   acceptable. Performance is restored after the data is accessed once.

I can think of 3 ways to address this issue:

1. The rest of the documentation
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-prewarm.html
   discusses ways to pre-warm the EBS volume prior to bringing it live
   (basically by reading all of the blocks on the volume). This may or
   may not be a useful way to address the problem for you.
2. You could hit specific database files as suggested by a mongodb blog
   post http://blog.mongodb.org/post/10407828262/cache-reheating-not-to-be-ignored :

   > On a server restart, copy datafiles to /dev/null to force reheating to
   >   be sequential and thus much faster. This can be done even if the
   >   mongod process is already running. If the database is larger than RAM,
   >   copy only the newest datafiles (ones with the highest numbers); while
   >   this isn’t perfect, the latest files likely contain the largest
   >   percentage of frequently used data.
3. You could use your already pre-warmed EBS volume from a secondary
   instead of the newly created volume. In this case you would take
   your secondary down, swap in the newly created volume and take the
   old volume for use with the new instance. This would take a few
   minutes but would provide you with a fully warmed up EBS volume
   probably faster than trying to pre-warm it yourself and performance
   should be better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you use dedicated Amazon EC2 instance for getting some data out and doing aggregation on client side.

Once you start EC2 instance memory would be in cold state, i.e. no data and indices are loaded in memory. Once you begin to send queries to box, only data that is accessed by queries and some indexes would be loaded in memory. So if you only use this box for getting some data, only data you need would be loaded. No need to prioritize, because only required data is loaded

You mentioned that it affects performance. Could you explain what do you mean? What amount of data do you try to retrieve on client?

Comment: I think you have understood me correctly. Okay: so perhaps mongo is already doing its best... To give a bit more detail; as soon as mongod is active on the box, I run a python script that does a simple find on an index into a collection that is circa 30GB with around 200M documents before looping over these documents and doing some processing. The find might hit in the order of a of million documents at a time. When the database is warm, my python process gets up to 100% CPU and does a couple of thousand documents / second but it takes up to 30 mins to hit those kind of levels.

Comment: Do you index collection before doing find? Indexing collection requires whole collection 30Gb to be loaded in memory.

Comment: Collection is indexed in the live database, therefore the index should already be memory mapped on disk on my snapshot shouldn't it?

Comment: It is ok then. So you do only one find request to db on this box? Could you provide explain() from this request to ensure that index is used?

Comment: I do a bunch of find requests one after another on the box; could easily parallelize those queries but was sceptical about whether it would help since bottleneck seems to be populating mongod's memory. Have just done an explain and realized it was not fully covered by index as I thought is was... rookie error! This helps.. will leave this question open for the weekend then accept your answer if nobody else comes in with any additional tips/ tricks

Comment: Nice, just ensure that you don't do full collection scan. It should reduce data have to be loaded in memory by mongo. Further improvement could be done if you start using EBS Provisioned IOPS. It helps to have fast seeks on drive which is very important for performance.

Comment: Yes we use Provisioned IOPS on our production database and they do seem to make quite a difference. Was trying to avoid using them here as they're expensive but looks like I may have to to avoid CPU starvation!